# Export slideshow as impress.js

Tags: export, slideshows

I have some slideshow notebooks I would like to share, however normal PDF/HTML export isn't up to the task. Does anyone know of a way to export the slides as part of an impress.js slide show? Perhaps there are some third party conversion tools out there?